# Can't read appSettings value from Web.Config

Tags: c#, web-config

I have the following in my web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="PsychMon" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>
 . . .
</configuration>
```

I have the following code in my codebehind:

```
  System.Configuration.Configuration webConfig = 
System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null) ;
```

However, when I look at webConfig, webConfig.AppSettings.Settings.Count = 0 .

Why is it not reading the app setting?

What I want to do is be able to get the setting by using:

```
          System.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationElement psych = 
webConfig.AppSettings.Settings["PsychMon"];
```

I am using c# 3.5, vs 2008

Comment: Are you sure you're accessing the right web.config?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why don't you just write this ?

```
string value = 
    System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PsychMon"];
```

Answer (score 3):

try this :

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PsychMon"];
```

or ( for global)

```
 Configuration webConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating the `webConfig` variable, why not just use `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PsychMon"]`