# Unable to read Web.config appSettings using WebConfigurationManager

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config

I have some application settings in my Web.config file, for sending email from within the system.  The relevant part reads:

```
<configuration>
...
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="emailRecipient" value="my email"/>
    <add key="emailSubject" value="subject"/>
        (other settings for contacting the mail server)
  </appSettings>
...
</configuration>
```

And in my repository, I use it like so:

using System.Web.Configuration;

```
MailModel email = new MailModel();
email.EmailTo = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailRecipient"];
email.Subject = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailSubject"];
```

Plus other lines to get the settings to contact the mail server.

The problem I'm having is that in the debugger, `WCM.AppSettings` contains 5 values:

```
WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys
{string[5]}
    [0]: "webpages:Version"
    [1]: "webpages:Enabled"
    [2]: "PreserveLoginUrl"
    [3]: "ClientValidationEnabled"
    [4]: "UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled"
```

What happened to my email config settings?

I checked with two other Stack Overflow questions to make sure I didn't make any obvious mistakes.  ([How to read appSettings section in the web.config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147220/how-to-read-appsettings-section-in-the-web-config-file) and [Can't read appSettings value from Web.Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651005/cant-read-appsettings-value-from-web-config))  So the problem is not obvious.

**Edited to add:**

I found my problem, and it's a bit embarrassing.  I had put the settings into `~/Views/Web.config` instead of `~/Web.config`.  Once I fixed that, the settings worked properly.  Mods, please close.

Comment: So it has keys in the debugger but doesn't have values? Personally, I sue `ConfigurationManager` everywhere and it works all the time

Comment: The debugger has the keys I listed, and the appropriate values for those.  It doesn't have my email keys.

Comment: Can you try `ConfigurationManager` and see if it works fine?

Comment: Got sidetracked by other work.  Will try that now.

Comment: Same results.  Bummer.

Comment: Are you sure that your properties are not overridden somehow in web config transformations files?

Comment: I'm sure, as I haven't entered the properties anywhere else.  But it would be good to confirm.  Where would I find a web.config transformation file?  I didn't create any on my own.

Comment: It's usually called Web.Debug.config and Web.Release.config and lie near the actual Web.config. You can also check that the web.config that's copied into `bin` folder contains the values your want

Comment: There's nothing set in `Web.config.debug`, and only a `<compilation />` tag set in `Web.config.release`.  There's no `Web.config` in my project `bin` directory.

Comment: In your `bin` folder there will be a `YourPRojectName.dll.config` file

Comment: There's only a `<runtime />` block in it, and none of the email config settings.  So they're not getting copied in.  Why not?  (That'll have to wait to after the weekend.)

Comment: That's strange, can you check if the build action for web.config file is `Content` and copying is set to `Do not copy` in the file properties?

Comment: That's what they are set to.  I presume those are the defaults.

Comment: **FACEPALM** I just found I had my email settings in `~/Views/Web.config` instead of `~/Web.config`.  Ow.  Now the settings are propagated to `~/bin/Project.dll.config` and show up properly in the debugger.

Comment: Lol! Good to hear that you've found the root of the problem!